# 500 error on .net core web api post using fetch

Tags: javascript, c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, fetch-api

I am using the javascript fetch api https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch
with a .net core 3 web api.

the controller returns OK(object)  but the fetch receives a 500 status code.

here is the controller. I can step through the code and see that it is returning Ok(customer)

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PostCustomerAsync([FromBody] Customers customer)
        {

            await _customersService.AddAsync(customer);
            return Ok(customer);
        }
    }
```

here is the fetch.

```
   fetch("./api/customers",
        {
            method: "POST", body: JSON.stringify(data),
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'text json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
        })
         .then(function(response, error){
             console.log(error);
             console.log(response);
             if(!response.ok){
                 console.log(response);
                 throw Error(response.statusText);
             }
             return response;
         }).then(function(response){
             Toastr.success(`${data.firstname} ${data.lastname} has been successfully registered`);  
             const bookChapterTable = new BookChapterTable();     
         }).catch(function(error){
             console.log(error);
             Toastr.error(`An error occured : ${error}`);        
         })
  }
```

the fetch is stopping at !response.ok

here is response.

```
body: ReadableStream
locked: false
__proto__: ReadableStream
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers {}
ok: false
redirected: false
status: 500
statusText: ""
type: "basic"
url: "https://localhost:44300/api/customers"
```

from network tab

```
Request URL: https://localhost:44300/api/customers
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 500 
Remote Address: [::1]:44300
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
date: Thu, 31 Oct 2019 18:34:14 GMT
server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
status: 500
x-powered-by: ASP.NET
:authority: localhost:44300
:method: POST
:path: /api/customers
:scheme: https
accept: text json
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
content-length: 171
```

Comment: add try catch and return the exception to see the problem or just debug, is problem it seems problem of `_customersService.AddAsync`

Comment: there is no exception in the controller.  I can see it hitting return OK(customer). the fetch does have a catch.

Comment: Can you please check in network tab / fiddler what is the API response status code? Is any pipeline throwing 500 error from web API?

Comment: added that info to the question

Comment: Try to remove `'Accept': 'text json',` and try with Postman

Comment: It's possible that Web API isn't able to serialize the object because of the invalid `Accept` header.

Comment: So, it's not a issue with `Fetch`. The Web API itself is returning 500 error. You need to check what are the steps being executed in your pipeline. One of them failing after processing Controller's response.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem. Error shown because I was't sending 'X-XSRF-Token' at header (it can be 'X-CSRF-TOKEN' depends from system). If anyone has same problem make sure you pass it at header.

```js
fetch(signUpEmailUrl, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'X-XSRF-Token': gettoken()
      },
      credentials: 'include',
      body: JSON.stringify({
          email: $('#sign_up_email').val(),
          firstName: $('#first_name').val(),
          lastName: $('#last_name').val(),
          token: $('#sign_up_token').val()
      })
  })
  .then(res => (res.json()))
  .then(data => {
      console.log(data);
      loginSuccess(data);
  })
  .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
  });
```

`